# Scala variances. What is this doing exactly?

Tags: scala

Say I see this:

```
object ThingA extends OtherThingA[ThingB, ThingA] {...
```

and this:

```
trait OtherThingA[B, A <: LastThing[B]] extends ...
```

What is this doing exactly?

Here is what I understand:

- ThingA is using the trait OtherThing and so **has** to implement the trait's methods or it now has access to the concrete public members.

I guess when we actually extends `OtherThingA`, we're extending it and declaring the types of it too which are `ThingB` and `ThingA`?

Comment: What is `LastThing`?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. `LastThing` should be `OtherThingA`. Then it's a duplicate of any other "What is F-bounded polymorphism" question.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Note that I didn't claim that OP *has* F-bounded-poly in his question. I only said that the code doesn't seem to compile as-is, and that replacing `LastThing` by `OtherThingA` seemed like the shortest way to make it compile. It was not a request to close, but rather to clarify the question (which *might* become a duplicate if it turns out to be yet another generic question about f-bounded poly).

Comment: It looks to me like OP is asking about 1) F-Bounded polymorphism 2) Upper Type Bound. I think he can get his answer from the duplicate. If not, I'll re-open.